# Parse a string to datetime format

Tags: c#

I have here a little problem and would like to know where is my mistake and how to correct it.

```
string preConvDATE = monthCombobox2.Text + " " + datecombobox2.Text + ","+ "0000";
//lets say the comboboxes contain something like this "January 1";

DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(preConvDATE, "MMMM d, yyyy 00:00:00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string strDate = DT.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
    try
    {
       //code that inserts strDate to a column in Mysql DB
    }
    catch
    {
      //msg
    }
```

why "0000" for the year? because i was really planning to store just the month and date, but realized i could just store it as a datetime format with a year, and then at viewing the table i'd just use the Mysql MONTH() and DATE() function concatenated to view the Month and Date i stored from the `monthCombobox2` and `datecombobox2`.

I also tried:

```
Convert.ToDateTime()
```

But still won't work.

How do i properly parse `MMMM d,yyyy` date format so that i could convert it to `yyyy-mm-dd` again and store it as `datetime` format in the database?
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Why do you need to format it as a string at all to insert it into MySql? You _are_ using parameterized SQL queries, right? (You should be)

Comment: Your main mistake is that you're building a string from user selections (when you could just construct a `DateTime` object using its constructor), and then trying to parse that string, and reformat it as another string. This is a very strange thing to do.

Comment: `new DateTime(year, month, day)`?

Comment: yes, im trying to store date events on the database. Just the Month and Day.

Comment: im really sorry, i actually dont know what im doing, im new to programming, and is trying to learn on my own, any correction is highly appreciated.

Comment: im sorry, i googled database format, and i really don't know if im giving u the correct answer but, i see a .sql whenever i back up my database on MySql Wamp Server.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what type of column are you using?

Comment: its a `date` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, you are using text boxes to catch the value of month and date, instead of that you can use dropdowns which will display the month name but return the values like 01 for January and so on. It will be easy for you to format date formats. You don't want to save year that's okay, instead of setting 0000 you can set the current year. Now the problem with that you will not able to figure out the what exactly day was it (e.g Sunday, Monday and so on).

```
string preConvDATE = monthCombobox2.Text + "/" + datecombobox2.Text+"/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(preConvDATE, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string strDate = DT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I hope this will solve your problem. Happy Coding!

Comment: yeah that's what i did :), and i did not parse the text anymore i just used Mysql Monthname() function to view the month number as month name. thank you for taking ur time to answer my qustion :)